# Change product prices

Tags: magento2, price

I need to know where catalog and cart prices are called to display so that I can calculate discounts via php and call the same function to display on screen.
The prices in question are those of the print below.
Searching I found the file Amount.php which is in "\ vendor \ magento \ framework \ Pricing \ Render" where I have the getDisplayValue () function
But changing only changes the prices of products without variations,
About the cart I have not yet found where the value is called and where the sum of the values ​​is made.

[image]

[image]

Magento 2.3.3
Win 10 Xampp

Comment: you have this running on XAMP on windows without issue?

Comment: Yes, no problem.

Comment: I'm envious, I just tried again and the web wizard just hung and via cli I got installed but cannot login and the default luma home is not right.  Anyhoo... if you solved it with your answer you can mark as answered for others to see.  Plus it's not enforced so much on this "stackoverflow" instance but it's nice to have some detail in the answer instead of link only, links can fail over time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will try to improve on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using the following tutorial
https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-to-change-product-price-with-plugin-magento-2.htmlt